# My global node_modules folder is inside the npm folder

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, command-line-interface

I'm not sure how this happened but when I install any npm package globally it is installing at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules. So with karma-cli for example if I try to run a command I'm getting a bash "command not found" error.

In /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ the only directory is npm/. If i navigate into the npm folder, there is a second node_modules directory, and I can see all my packages there. I know I can just copy them into the correct folder but how do I fix where `npm install -g` installs something?

I'm using mac terminal and OS El Capitan 10.11.6. This is what I get when I run printenv in terminal. (I deleted unrelated things)

```
MANPATH=/Users/Blair/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/X11/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
NVM_PATH=/Users/Blair/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/lib/node

OLDPWD=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
PATH=/Users/Blair/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin:/Users/Blair/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/Blair/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist
PWD=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules
NVM_BIN=/Users/Blair/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin
```

Comment: did you try npm install -g package_name

Comment: yes I did that... That's what I meant by "install a package globally" @SagarRanaMagar